# Get zoom value when zoom is changed in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to show some Sprites when the camera gets close to a building and when the camera zoom out, remove the Sprites.

Is there any event that triggered when zoom changes? Also, How can we get the current zoom value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an event trigerred when Camera changes (included zoom) :

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

There is a zoom property in the event received. You will additionally find a lot of informations

Comment: In my experiment, `e.camera.zoom` is always `1`, but some other properties like `e.camera.near` and `e.camera.far` are changed when zoom changes. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, I found out this value is always 1 even after using mouse wheel of zoom button but I have no idea why. Maybe a bug, or maybe it relay to another function of the viewer